# woocommerce category image load to loop-theme-search (Mustang Lite theme) doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to show the woocommerce category image. If a product doesn't have an image I try this code but it doesn't work. I don't know what I did wrong. With this code show src"(unknown)".

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    // thets work ok .....
}else{
global $wp_query;
// get the query object
$cats = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
// get the thumbnail id using the queried category term_id
$thumbnail_ids = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cats->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
// get the image URL
$images = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_ids ); 
$output .= '<a href="'.$urllink.'" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">';
$output .= '<img src="' . $images . '" alt="Placeholder" width="300" class="woocommerce-placeholder wp-post-image" height="300">';
$output .= '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID ) ) {
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog' );
    } else {
        echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder" />';
    }
?>
```